# LEFT OUTER JOIN MATCHING

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I have the following query, I modified it to be able to look in a new table called Futuredial_Validation, I wrote all the conditions and the joins but its still don't looking in the table, just in the one called cellscripter, the rest of the query works, I really appreciate any help, thanks:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate, wms_us.wms_us.rrno.pono, wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, att.Date_cleared) AS ROW_ID,
  wms_us.wms_us.rrno.pono                                                                                                                      AS ATT_PO,
  wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate                                                                                                                    AS Received_Date,
  CASE
    WHEN (wms_us.wms_us.model.modeldesc = 'MIXED')
    THEN wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.basemodel
    ELSE wms_us.wms_us.model.modelbase
  END AS Model,
  CASE
    WHEN LEN(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex) >= 15
    THEN LEFT(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, 14)
    ELSE wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex
  END AS IMEI,
  /*Check in Futerdial else obtain the values from cellscripter*/
  CASE
    WHEN (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
    THEN Future.LocalTime
    ELSE att.Date_cleared
  END AS Date_cleared,
  CASE
    WHEN (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
    THEN 'PASS'
    ELSE att.Result
  END AS Result
FROM wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc
INNER JOIN wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet
ON wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc.transferboxdocid = wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.transferboxdocid
INNER JOIN wms_us.wms_us.rrno
ON wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.rrnoid = wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrnoid
INNER JOIN wms_us.wms_us.model
ON wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc.modelid = wms_us.wms_us.model.modelid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Futerdial.dbo.Futuredial_Validation AS Future
ON Future.IMEI = LEFT(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, 14)
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRSCSQLQADB01.att_view2.dbo.attview2 AS att
ON att.IMEI                      = LEFT(wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet.meidhex, 14)
WHERE (wms_us.wms_us.rrno.rrdate > '2016-12-01')
```

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you're trying to accomplish, as well as either simplifying your schema or giving us some further detail on the schema - it's a bit difficult to guess at what you're going for, especially with all the strange table names and 4-part notation.

Comment: Use some tables aliases here. three and four part naming in the columns like this has been deprecated.

Comment: please look here to improve your question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm try to accomplish:

Comment: First I have an IMEI, I need to check if the IMEI passed the analysis, usually this information is in a table called Cellscripter but now there are some IMEI included in a table called Futuredial_Validation, what I need to do is be able to check in both tables, if I can't find and IMEI in one looking in the other one, in Futuredial_Validation if the IMEI passed the Error Code =1. I don't know why is not checking in Futuredial_Validation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely: either your join specification is not working or the `case` expression for the `[Error Code]` is not correct.

Check if you get any values for `[Future_imei]` and `[Error Code]` with this:

```
select
    row_id = row_number() over (
      order by rrno.rrdate
        , rrno.pono
        , tbdet.meidhex
        , att.Date_cleared)
  , att_po = rrno.pono
  , Received_Date = rrno.rrdate
  , Model=case
      when (m.modeldesc = 'mixed')
        then tbdet.basemodel
      else m.modelbase
      end
  , imei=case
      when len(tbdet.meidhex) >= 15
        then left(tbdet.meidhex, 14)
      else tbdet.meidhex
      end 
  , [Future_imei] = Future.imei
  , Future.[Error Code]
  , Date_cleared=case
      when (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
        then Future.LocalTime
      else att.Date_cleared
      end 
  , [Result]=case
      when (Future.[Error Code] = '1')
        then 'pass'
      else att.Result
      end 
from wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdoc as tbdoc
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.transferboxdet as tbdet
    on tbdoc.transferboxdocid = tbdet.transferboxdocid
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.rrno as rrno
    on tbdet.rrnoid = rrno.rrnoid
  inner join wms_us.wms_us.model as m
    on tbdoc.modelid = m.modelid
  left outer join Futerdial.dbo.Futuredial_Validation as Future
      on Future.imei = left(tbdet.meidhex, 14)
  left outer join drscsqlqadb01.att_view2.dbo.attview2 as att
      on att.imei = left(tbdet.meidhex, 14)
  where (rrno.rrdate > '2016-12-01')
```

Comment: No I don't, all the values for Future_imei and Error Code are null, why is this happening!??

Comment: I'm guessing your join condition is wrong `Future.imei = left(tbdet.meidhex, 14)`

Comment: ... Look at your data in those tables and see if that should match, and if not find what would?

Comment: All the tables have the value IMEI